# svn:ignore all subdirectories

Tags: svn, ignore, svnignore

My output from svn st looks like this:

```
?       wp-content/uploads/2012/07/file.jpg
?       wp-content/uploads/2012/07/some_other_file.jpg
?       wp-content/uploads/2012/08/more_file.jpg
?       wp-content/uploads/2012/08/another_jpeg.jpg
```

I don't want ANY of the files inside `uploads\2012` to sync (but I DO want the `uploads` folder to be in the repo, as well as some other stuff that's in there). So I do:

`svn propedit svn:ignore wp-content/uploads`

And add:

```
2012
2012/*
```

`svn st` still shows all those new files in 2012/

Fine, I must not be understanding svn:ignore, so let's try

`svn propset svn:ignore '*' wp-content/uploads/2012`

Meh. `svn st` STILL shows all those uploads.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the files in the 2012/... tree part of your SVN repository? If they are, they will be listed, even with the ignore.

Comment: @AlG I'm not sure I understand the question. These are all files that have been added to the local working copy, but I do not want them synced to the repo. So they are new files, unversioned (hence the "?" from `svn st`). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes! Did you try a `svn clean` after your `svn prop...`?

Comment: @AlG if you mean `svn cleanup` I just did that, but no dice.